# Analityc curve can be closed?

Tags: curves

An excercise tell me to represent a revolution surface by rotating an analityc curve around the x-axis. So my idea is to consider a generic analityc curve so described by a cartesian equation, for example y=x. My question is: among the analityc curve I should consider also the closed curve as a circle?

Comment: You could consider rotating a full circle through $\pi$ radians (circle center on rotation axis). But some methods require a single function, then rotate only a semicircle through $2 \pi.$

Comment: @ coffeemath But in essence the analityc curves are only open curves?

Comment: Nik-- Are you using a particular definition of "analytic curve"? Because the curve $x^2+y^2=1$ in the plane is [to me] definitely analytic, and it is a closed curve, a circle.